# Service pn-requester (2717) port information

Tags: port-scanning

I have not found big information on the internet about what does this service and for what is used.

I apreciate if someone can explain to me a little.

Thank you

Comment: If you explain why you are looking for this information, it will also become more clear, what information you are looking for.

Are you seeing someone communicate using this port number and want to know what it is? If that's the case, then information about which process is communicating and what is in the packets being exchanged, may tell much more than the port number.

Also, some systems allocate ephemeral ports starting from 1024 and going up. It is not impossible ephemeral port numbers on such a system could reach 2717. If that's the case, then the port number will tell you nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you scanned a host and Port 2717 is listed as "pn-requester"? This information is from your local "/etc/services" therefore it's not necessarily a service called "pn-requester" running on that host.

You can change the relation between service and port in /etc/services. Add a line like `myservice      2717/tcp` to your /etc/services and rescan now you will see port 2717 as "myservice"